# How to map collections of immutable objects in Dozer

Tags: java, immutability, dozer

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29284040/878514), I have wrote a custom conveter (you can find the whole working example in the [Github repo](https://github.com/fracz/stackoverflow-problems/tree/dozer-mapping-object-id)). for Dozer to convert between:

```
public class MyEntity {
    private List<ObjectId> attachmentIds;

    public List<ObjectId> getAttachmentIds() { return attachmentIds; }

    public void setAttachmentIds(List<ObjectId> attachmentIds) {
        this.attachmentIds = attachmentIds;
    }
}
```

And its DTO:

```
public class MyEntityDto {
    private List<FileDataDto> attachments;

    public List<FileDataDto> getAttachments() { return attachments; }

    public void setAttachments(List<FileDataDto> attachments) {
        this.attachments = attachments;
    }
}
```

`MyEntity` holds only the ids for files stored in Mongo databse. Its DTO which is sent to frontend in JSON, is supposed to contain both id and a filename of a file (which is the content of the `FileDataDto` class). My Converter:

```
public class FileIdToFileDataConverter extends DozerConverter<ObjectId, FileDataDto> {
    public FileIdToFileDataConverter() {super(ObjectId.class, FileDataDto.class); }

    @Override
    public FileDataDto convertTo(ObjectId source, FileDataDto destination) {
        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }
        FileDataDto fileData = destination == null ? new FileDataDto() : destination;
        fileData.setId(source.toString());
        // fetch the file from repository and update the name from db
        fileData.setFilename("myfile.txt");
        return fileData;
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectId convertFrom(FileDataDto source, ObjectId destination) {
        return source == null ? null : new ObjectId(source.getId());
    }
}
```

The conversion works as expected in the `MyEntity` -> `MyEntityDto` direction. However, it fails in the opposite. It uses the `ObjectId` created by Dozer  (passed as the `destination` argument) instead of the one that is returned by the converter. This test

```
@Test
public void dtoToMyEntity() {
    MyEntityDto dto = new MyEntityDto();
    FileDataDto fileData = new FileDataDto();
    fileData.setFilename("file.txt");
    fileData.setId(new ObjectId().toString());
    dto.setAttachments(Arrays.asList(fileData));
    MyEntity myEntity = mapper.map(dto, MyEntity.class);
    assertEquals(fileData.getId(), myEntity.getAttachmentIds().get(0).toString());
}
```

Fails with an example message:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
  Expected :56b0a9d110a937fc32a6db18
  Actual   :56b0a9d110a937fc32a6db19
```

You can find the whole test and configuration I use in the [Github repo](https://github.com/fracz/stackoverflow-problems/blob/dozer-mapping-object-id/src/test/java/com/example/mapping/DozerMappingImmutableTest.java).

How to make the converter work in both ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's connected with bug in dozer, which causes that custom converters are not used when mapped through API: https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer/issues/242

**So you can provide either mapping through xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net
          http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">
    <configuration>
        <custom-converters>
            <converter type="com.example.mapping.FileIdToFileDataConverter">
                <class-a>org.bson.types.ObjectId</class-a>
                <class-b>com.example.mapping.entity.FileDataDto</class-b>
            </converter>
        </custom-converters>
    </configuration>
    <mapping>
        <class-a>com.example.mapping.entity.MyEntity</class-a>
        <class-b>com.example.mapping.entity.MyEntityDto</class-b>
        <field>
            <a>attachmentIds</a>
            <b>attachments</b>
            <a-hint>org.bson.types.ObjectId</a-hint>
            <b-hint>com.example.mapping.entity.FileDataDto</b-hint>
        </field>
    </mapping>
</mappings>
```

And then

```
mapper.setMappingFiles(Arrays.asList("dozerconfig.xml"));
```

**Or, if you don't want to use xml, you can create a workaround for using own ObjectIdFactory**:

```
mapping(type(ObjectId.class).beanFactory(ObjectIdFactory.class), FileDataDto.class)
    .fields(this_(), this_(), customConverter(FileIdToFileDataConverter.class));
```

And the factory class

```
public class ObjectIdFactory implements BeanFactory {
    @Override
    public Object createBean(Object source, Class<?> sourceClass, String targetBeanId) {
        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (source instanceof ObjectId) {
            return source; // we can return source, because it's immutable
        }
        if (source instanceof String) {
            return new ObjectId((String) source);
        }
        if (source instanceof FileDataDto) {
            return new ObjectId(((FileDataDto) source).getId());
        }
        throw new MappingException("ObjectId should be of type ObjectId, String or FileDataDto");
    }
}
```

**The reason why this workaroud works and why ids didn't match**:

Dozer by default uses no-args constructor of class to instantiate null values. ObjectId is immutable class and it's no-args constructor creates new instance based on timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler alternative is using [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) It supports immutables out of the box ([including Lombok's and Immutable's builders](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-with-builders)).

Minimal code example (from the docs):

```java
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper { 
    CarMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CarMapper.class);
    CarDto carToCarDto(Car car);
}

// Usage:
CarDto carDto = CarMapper.INSTANCE.carToCarDto(car);
```